# How to run Bokeh server on Streamlit

Tags: python, bokeh, streamlit

I would like to show an interactive Bokeh plot on Streamlit but I am not able to add a widget to the plot. The plot with show(p) command shows on a tab but I cannot show the widget. The Bokeh serve show command works perfectly but how can I use it inside Streamlit.

```
import pandas as pd
import streamlit as st
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, Select
from bokeh.plotting import figure,ColumnDataSource, show
from bokeh.models import FactorRange
from bokeh.models import NumeralTickFormatter
from math import radians
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, Grid, LinearAxis, Plot, VBar
from bokeh.io import curdoc, show
from bokeh.models import HoverTool
from bokeh.models.widgets import Slider
from bokeh.layouts import column, row
import streamlit


 st.title("Hello world!")

 uploaded_file = st.file_uploader("Choose a file")
 if uploaded_file is not None:
    df = pd.read_excel(uploaded_file)


    df = pd.read_excel("C:/Users/Files/Data.xls")
    df1 = df.groupby(['A','B'])['C'].sum().reset_index()
    #st.write(df1)
    df2 = df1.sort_values(by=['B'], ascending=False)

    st.write(df2)


    data_source = ColumnDataSource(df2)

    x = 10

    range = FactorRange(factors=list(df2.iloc[:x]['A'].unique()))

      p = figure(x_range = range ,plot_height=600,title="Top Spend by 
      Vendors",toolbar_location=None, plot_width=1200)
      r = p.vbar(x='A', top='B', width=0.04, color ='red', source=data_source)
      p.yaxis.formatter=NumeralTickFormatter(format="$0,0")
      p.xaxis.major_label_orientation=radians(60)


      def update_plot(attr, old, new):    
         label = "Siddharth"
         v_custom = streamlit.slider(label,10,30,5, step=1)
         st.write('Values:', v_custom)
         range = FactorRange(factors=list(df2.iloc[:v_custom]['Supplier'].unique()))
         Currnew = ColumnDataSource(df2[['A', 'B']])
         p.x_range.factors = list(df_filter1['Vendor'].unique())
          r.data_source.data = Currnew.data

        v_custom.on_change('value', update_plot)
```

Answer (score 0):

Bokeh 2.0 is broken while using in streamlit.
Use the earlier version to use bokeh in streamlit

Comment: My plot shows up on Streamlit using show(p) command but the widget feature is something I cannot introduce in my plot. Do you see an error in my code?